Sidebar positioned wrong in the appbar
I am trying to do a flutter app and I used rive for the animation of the sidebar. I added the button in my appbar but I think it is wrong and if I added it in my homepage and erase the entire appbar it messing with my homepage by staying behind it. here it's the code
  Widget _homePage() {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return loadingUsers == true
        ? SizedBox(
            height: height,
            width: width,
            child: const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          )
        : Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                    bottom: Radius.circular(30),
                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  MenuBtn(press: () {
                    isSideBarClosed.value = !isSideBarClosed.value;
                    setState(() {
                      isSideMenuClosed = isSideBarClosed.value;
                    });
                  }, riveOnInit: (artboard) {
                    StateMachineController controller =
                        RiveUtils.getRiveController(artboard,
                            stateMachine: "State Machine");
                    isSideBarClosed = controller.findSMI("isOpen") as SMIBool;
                    isSideBarClosed.value = true;
                  }),     ]),
            body: Stack(children: [
 Positioned(
                  width: 288,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: SideMenu()),
              Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset( isSideMenuClosed ? 0 :288, 0),
                child: Transform.scale(
                  scale: isSideMenuClosed ? 1 : 0.8,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        child: Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          children: [
                            Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child: TextField(
                                  readOnly: true,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: "Cauta Business"),
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    User user =
                                        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
                                    navigateToSearchPage(user.uid);
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Column(children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 100.0, left: 20.0),
                                child: const Text(
                                  "Exploreaza cele mai populare categorii",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                                      fontSize: 18),
                                ),
                              ),

                              const CategoriesScroller(),
                              const TopText(),
                              showAnotherData(),
                              //Appbar()
                            ]),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ]),
          );
  }

This is the outcome https://imgur.com/a/GExv3d0.
Any idea of what is wrong?

Replace body -> SingleChildScrollview -> SizedBox to Container and give color white to that container.

Thank youuu! but how I can make it to not interfere so much with the appbar , to be over the appbar and scaffold? and also to not mess up so much with text , it is possible? https://imgur.com/a/5WLhdy5

Try to replace offset: Offset(isSideMenuClosed ? 0 : 288, 0)  with offset: Offset(isSideMenuClosed ? 0 : 100, 0),

I increased and it helped a bit but how can I move the button in scaffold and deactivate the appbar because I think it's messed up because of it https://imgur.com/a/EpGBJUw also there is black stuff next to my bottom bar I don't know why (at the left)

Please share your output which is working now.

I moved the MenuBtn first thing in the stack and it completely disappeared  and if I try to scroll up I can see the SideMenu https://imgur.com/a/R1bty2x

https://imgur.com/a/8VLNfsk

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Try to wrap Stack in SafeArea and add physics: ClampingScrollPhysics() to SingleChildScrollView for scrolling issue.
body: 
      SafeArea(
        child: Stack(children: [
          Positioned(width: 288,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, child: SideMenu()),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(isSideMenuClosed ? 0 : 100, 0),
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: isSideMenuClosed ? 1 : 0.8,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(isSideMenuClosed?0:24)),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      children: [
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: TextField(
                              readOnly: true,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText:
                              "Cauta Business"),
                              onTap: () async {},
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Column(children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0, left: 20.0),
                            child: const Text(
                              "Exploreaza cele mai populare categorii",
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'Helvetica', fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                          ),

                          CategoriesScroller(),
                          TopText(),
                          ShowAnotherData(),
                          //Appbar()
                        ]),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),


it is not changing anything
